# Русский язык в Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Как использовать русскоязычные блоки комментариев Doxygen в исходниках с ANSI кодировкой? 
После обработки Doxygen получается белеберда.

Comment: А как включить поиск по кириллице? Ищет только те функции, которые написаны латиницей:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конфиге Doxygen есть переменная INPUT_ENCODING, укажите кодировку там (ANSI это CP1251 для русскоязычной windows).

Comment: Спасибо. Здорово помогло. А я пытался Doxyfile encoding поменять зачем-то.